# awk print sums of every line, but how to exclude all numbers left from a character

Tags: awk

I am using

```
awk '{s=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) s=s+$i; print s}'
```

that prints the sums of the fields of every line.
How can I avoid that numbers that are left from the character  §
are included?
Numbers between § and § are excluded anyway

```
hrur ueueu 5 ue eeuhe 17 jej 8 kejhfj  
jehe 7 hhhd 5  §ir5uj§ irur 17 jjjhr 8  
plkkwej 8 §h8sq§ oaiwhe 77 jjwgd 33
```

result:

```
30  
25  
110
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you loop over the fields, remove everything left of `§`:

```
awk '{s = 0; sub(".*§", ""); for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) s=s+$i; print s}'
```